# Radio Button not working when clicked in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button, radio-group

I'm using Alarm Manager and It has radio button,when clicked radio button the alarm will postpone for the time intervals like 1,3,5,10,15 and 30 minutes.

This is the Fragment.class

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment{
Context context;
RadioGroup radio;
int Aplazar;
AlarmManager alarm_Manager;
PendingIntent pending_intent;
Intent mi_intent;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_repetir, container,
            false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Dia de la Semana");
    alarm_Manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    final Intent mi_intent = new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);
    radio = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    Log.e("Entro a Clase Dfragment","2");

    radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn) {

                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 1;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn0) {
                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 3;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);


            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn1) {
                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 5;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);


            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn2) {
                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 10;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);


            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn3) {
                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 15;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);


            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Rbtn4) {
                alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_off");
                context.sendBroadcast(mi_intent);

                Aplazar = 30;
                mi_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm_on");

                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mi_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarm_Manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Aplazar * 1000, pending_intent);


            }
        }
    });
    Button Desplazar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarDezplazar);

    final RadioButton Rbtn0 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn0);
    final RadioButton Rbtn = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn);
    final RadioButton Rbtn1 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn1);
    final RadioButton Rbtn2 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn2);
    final RadioButton Rbtn3 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn3);
    final RadioButton Rbtn4 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rbtn4);

    Desplazar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }

    });
    return rootView;
}}
```

and this is the MainActivity.class

```
public class PosponerAcivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
AlarmManager alarm_Manager;
PendingIntent pending_intent;
Intent mi_intent;
Context context;
TimePicker alarm_timepicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posponer_acivity);
    alarm_Manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    final Intent mi_intent = new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);

    Button Posponer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPosponer);
    Posponer.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button Parar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnParar);
    Parar.setOnClickListener(this);

    Parar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Entro a Clase Posponer","Entro a boton PARAR");

            alarm_Manager.cancel(pending_intent);
            mi_intent.putExtra("extra","alarm_off");
            sendBroadcast(mi_intent);
            finish();
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentAlarm);
        }
    });


    Posponer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RadioButton Rbtn0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn0);
            RadioButton Rbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn);
            RadioButton Rbtn1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn1);
            RadioButton Rbtn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn2);
            RadioButton Rbtn3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn3);
            RadioButton Rbtn4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Rbtn4);

            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPosponer) {

                Log.e("Entro a Clase Posponer", "Entro a boton Posponer");
                try {
                    DFragmentDesplazar dFragmentDs = new DFragmentDesplazar();
                    // Show DialogFragment
                    dFragmentDs.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(null, "error");
                }
            }
        }
    });


}

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    }
```

}

Comment: you have provided detailed info but have not specified your question. what are you trying to do/what would you like help with?

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of context here `alarm_Manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);` , you didn't initialized the context

Comment: Sorry, I am using a radiobutton in a fragment but when I press the radiobutton in the app nothing happens so i want to know whats wrong with it. Implements RadioGroups but it didn't work either, i wrote a Log.e into de fragment class but never read the Log.e

Comment: the radio button is working now. i use getActivity() and 
it worked ,thank you :D